# What are Switch classes used for?

Tags: java, eclipse, emf

What are switch classes (derived from `org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util.Switch<T>`) used for?

The [javadoc](http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/emf/javadoc/2.7.0/org/eclipse/emf/ecore/util/Switch.html) explains it as

> An abstract base class for all switch classes.

which does not help as I have never heared about "switch classes" before.

Comment: It's a eclipse framework class used in abstract factories to create objects based on a model object's type.  Having not used eclipse RCP properly, I don't feel like I can answer the question in whole.  But there's some info [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ff-9ZYhvPwwC&pg=PA207&lpg=PA207&dq=eclipse+%22switch+classes%22&source=bl&ots=yAWqE2sSsF&sig=g0Z6CGmXW1AHu6eb39e2zW36CSs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CD4Q6AEwBGoVChMIv7HMjY6VyQIVhb8UCh2Yhgxx#v=onepage&q=eclipse%20%22switch%20classes%22&f=false)

Comment: If you summarize that, as to remove the dependency on that external site, then I'll accept it as a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A switch class is a class that allows you to choose and instantiates a concrete instance of a type based on a model object (in this case, an EMF model object).  The examples I've seen suggest it's useful for instantiating type-specific adapters for an EMF model.

You use it by overriding the doSwitch method.  For instance, say I've got a model object, and I want to instantiate an adapter object that corresponds to the `type` value in my model:

```
public class ExampleSwitch extends Switch<Adapter> {

    public Adapter doSwitch(EObject eobject) {
        if (eobject instanceof MyModel) {
            switch (eobject.getType()) {
                case TYPEA:
                    Adapter result = createTypeAAdapter(eobject);
                    if (result == null) {
                        return createDefaultAdapter(eobject);
                    }
                    return result;
                case TYPEB:
                    ...
                default:
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

An eclipse org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.AdapterFactory would then use this to return an Adapter.

```
public class MyAdapterFactory implements AdapterFactory {
    public boolean isFactoryForType(Object o) {
        return (o instanceof MyModel);
    }
    public Adapter adapt(Notifier notifier, Object type) {
        return mySwitch.doSwitch((EObject)notifier);
    }
}
```

I've pulled this information from [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ff-9ZYhvPwwC&pg=PA207&lpg=PA207&dq=eclipse%20%22switch%20classes%22&source=bl&ots=yAWqE2sSsF&sig=g0Z6CGmXW1AHu6eb39e2zW36CSs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CD4Q6AEwBGoVChMIv7HMjY6VyQIVhb8UCh2Yhgxx#v=onepage&q=eclipse%20%22switch%20classes%22&f=false).  I haven't verified this, but apparently the EMF generator can optionally generate your AdapterFactories and Switch classes for you.

Comment: This answer is highly misleading.  The point of the class is to avoid using `instanceof` checks, which are an antipattern.  The Switch class extension generated for your model (seek under util) already hides this logics. You are supposed to overload caseXXX functions from that type, not the doSwitch method. Then answer by lorenzo-bettini below is much better, and should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 5):

EMF generates a utility class derived from `org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util.Switch<T>` for your metamodel allowing you to "easily" visit your EMF model according to the actual types of the objects, taking into consideration the inheritance relations.

Indeed, the Javadoc in the generated utility class states

> The Switch for the model's inheritance hierarchy. It supports the call doSwitch(object) to invoke the caseXXX method for each class of the model, starting with the actual class of the object and proceeding up the inheritance hierarchy until a non-null result is returned, which is the result of the switch.

This way, you don't have to manually implement a *Visitor* class yourself and you can rely on such a generated utility class. The generated switch class is also a generic class so that you can use it for computing any type of values.

The idea is that you create a subclass of the generated switch class and override only the caseXXX methods for the model elements you want to process. Then you create an instance of such a subclass and you call `doSwitch` passing an instance of your model.

You have an caseXXX method for each XXX type in your metamodel. You also have a `defaultCase()` method for the default case, that is, when no other case method matches.

For example if you have in your metamodel the types `A`, `B1` and `B2` then you have in the generated switch class the methods `caseA`, `caseB1` and `caseB2` that you can redefine. Keep in mind that the default implementation simply returns `null`. If `B1` and `B2` are subtypes of `A`, and you redefine only `caseA` and `caseB1`, then if you call `doSwitch` passing `B1` then the method `caseB1` will be used. If you call `doSwitch` passing `B2` then the method `caseA` will be used: in fact, there's no `caseB2`, but `B1` is a subtype of `A`.

For example, for the Ecore model itself you have `org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util.EcoreSwitch`. This an example, in the shape of a JUnit test, where a subclass of `EcoreSwitch` is created to visit an Ecore model (it simply returns a string with some information, note that it also visits the children):

```java
public class EcoreSwitchTest {

    private static EcoreFactory factory = EcoreFactory.eINSTANCE;

    @Test public void exampleEcoreSwitch() {
        // given
        EAttribute eAttribute = factory.createEAttribute();
        EReference eReference = factory.createEReference();
        EClass eClass = factory.createEClass();
        eClass.getEStructuralFeatures().add(eAttribute);
        eClass.getEStructuralFeatures().add(eReference);

        EDataType eDataType = factory.createEDataType();

        EPackage ePackage = factory.createEPackage();
        ePackage.getEClassifiers().add(eClass);
        ePackage.getEClassifiers().add(eDataType);

        EcoreSwitch<String> mySwitch = new EcoreSwitch<String>() {
            @Override
            public String caseEClass(EClass c) {
                return "EClass\n" +
                        c.getEStructuralFeatures().stream()
                            .map(this::doSwitch)
                            .collect(Collectors.joining());
            };

            @Override
            public String caseEAttribute(EAttribute a) {
                return "  EAttribute\n";
            };

            @Override
            public String caseEStructuralFeature(EStructuralFeature f) {
                return "  EStructuralFeature("
                        + f.eClass().getName() + ")\n";
            };

            @Override
            public String defaultCase(EObject o) {
                return "Unknown\n";
            };
        };

        // when
        String result = ePackage.getEClassifiers().stream()
                            .map(o -> mySwitch.doSwitch(o))
                            .collect(Collectors.joining());

        // then
        assertEquals(
                "EClass\n" + // caseEClass
                "  EAttribute\n" + // caseEAttribute
                "  EStructuralFeature(EReference)\n" + // caseEStructuralFeature
                "Unknown\n" + // defaultCase
                "", result);
    }
}
```

As you can see, `caseEStructuralFeature` catches an `EReference` since there's no `caseEReference` but not an `EAttribute` since there's the more specific `caseEAttribute`.

Again, by deriving from the Switch class generated by EMF for your metamodel you can easily visit your models.

Answer (score -6):

Everything in Java is class. (Except primitives). So when you use `switch`, behind the scenes you call a class that has all the logic for `switch`. `Switch<T>` is probably class from which other switch classes inherit and implement methods when you use them. For example you can use `switch(int)` or you can use `switch(String)` and both functionalities are different and have to be defined somewhere.