# Factory pattern and Polymorphism

Tags: java, polymorphism, factory-pattern

My plan is to have a `ControlPanelFactory` that will build a customized `ControlPane` for each of the different `Model` classes:

```
abstact class Model {
}

class ModelA extends Model {
}

class ModelB extends Model {
}
```

Now my plan was to have the Factory class that creates different `ControlPane` instances based on the `Model` class that was passed with method overloading:

```
class ControlPaneFactory {
    private ControlPaneFactory() {
    }

    public static ControlPanel build(ModelA model) {
        return new ControlPaneA(model);
    }

    public static ControlPanel build(ModelB model) {
        return new ControlPaneB(model);
    }
}
```

However this is very problematic, because when calling the factorys method, I only have a variable of type `Model`, so I would need to use `instanceof` first, which is a huge codesmell. The same apllies to having a condensed factory method:

```
public static ControlPane build(Model model) {
    if (model instanceof ModelA) 
        return new ControlPaneA(model);
    else if (model instanceof ModelB) 
        return new ControlPaneB(model);
    else throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported model");
}
```

I thought about usign an enum inside the model classes that would specify the type of `Model`, however this also seems like a bad option that would violate DRY.

Additionally I would much prefer to have the instantiation of the `ControlPane` independent (i.e. in a spererate class) of the `Model` classes . Is there a "nice" way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

If you want all of your factory methods in the same object, then you will one way or another need a switch/instanceof if group, or a map of `Models` to `ControlPanels`.

Alternatively, you could move the factory method to the `Model` class.  Essentially, this is the abstract factory pattern, but you're implementing it using your `Model` objects.  There's a few ways of looking at this.  It could be argued it increases coupling between your `Model` and `ControlPanel` pairs, but I'd suggest you're trying to achieve that.  It could also be argued it makes your factory code less reuseable as you need a `Model` object to run it, but the example interface you've given for the factory object requires a built `Model` anyways.  With the move away from anemic models, I think it's a reasonable way of implementing it, and reduces complexity in your factory object (if you still need it).

I'd go with something like this:

```
abstact class Model {
    public abstract ControlPanel buildControlPanel();
}

class ModelA extends Model {
    public ControlPanel buildControlPanel() {
        return new ControlPanelA(this);
    }
}

class ModelB extends Model {
    public ControlPanel buildControlPanel() {
        return new ControlPanelB(this);
    }
}

// Don't really need this anymore...
class ControlPaneFactory {
    public static ControlPanel build(Model model) {
        return model.buildControlPanel();
    }
}
```

This will still allow you to have the flexibility of wildly different constructors for your `ControlPanel`s if required, and you won't need to register a map of objects when your program starts.

You could move the `buildControlPanel()` method out of your `Model`s, and create a proper abstract factory pattern, and instead return a concrete factory from your `Model` objects.  But I feel like that would just increase the number of classes you have without actually providing any real improvement.  If you have a lot of `Model` classes that use the same build code (like `ModelA`, `ModelB`, `ModelC` all correspond to `ControlPanelX`), then it might be a good way to go, but it doesn't sound like you're doing that.

At the end of the day though, a switch or if statement to choose the concrete class to instantiate is not the worst thing in the world.  Other libraries have used similar things, such as [Eclipse's EMF Switch Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33705614/what-are-switch-classes-used-for).

Comment: Moving the instantiation of the `ControlPane` to the respective `Model` classes would be the obvious solution but as you said, this does increase coupling between view and model which is what I am trying to avoid. Abstract Factory would be overkill for sure. I was just wondering if there was an obvious and elegant way this could be solved, but it seems like if you want uncouple the `ControlPanel` from the `Model`, there will always be something that doesn't feel quite elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to make your code more generic, meaning that you ControlPanel shouldn't be dependend on a specific Model. However if it is really necessary you can try this:

```
public class ControlPanelFactory {
    private static Map<Class<? extends Model>, Class<? extends ControlPanel>> modelPanelMap = new HashMap<>();

    public static void addModelPaneRelation(Class<? extends Model> model, Class<? extends ControlPanel> pane) {
        modelPanelMap.put(model, pane);
    }

    public static ControlPanel build(Model model) {
        try {
            return modelPanelMap.get(model.getClass())
                    .getConstructor(model.getClass())
                    .newInstance(model);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            // Handle exceptions
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

When you boot your application you should have some sort of configuration. Which executes it like this:

```
ControlPanelFactory.addModelPaneRelation(ModelA.class, ControlPanel.class);
```

At least this will extract the logic how Panel are dependent on Model. Again I don't think this is the cleanest solution.